# Adverb of frequncy, word order question

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, word-order, frequency

I’m an English teacher of young learners.

I ‘ve got a question about a sentence from an online present simple exercise:

Here is the example:

(she / dance often)?

That's the correct answer given by the author of the exercise:

[ Does she dance often? ]
I thougth the proper word order is
[ Does she often dance?}

***My question is:*
Is it a problem if OFTEN is at the end of the sentence?
Is it too wierd about grammar exercises for students of A2 level or it's OK?**

I've found here the following piece of information, which mainly answers my question but I will be happy if someone else shares their opinion.
P.S. Is it ok if I use "their" instead of "his/ her" in my previous sentence? (I've noticed recently unisex words are very trendy, although not a big fan of that trend.)  Which one sounds better "their" or "his/ her"?
What about /answerS/ and /shareS/ is the S-form of the third person of the proper usage here?

> Adverbs as (sometimes, seldom, usually) we can put into the beginning,
> end, between pronoun and verb
>
> but the adverb 'always' sounds good only between pronoun and verb, in
> other cases, it sounds weird (Always, I do it in the morning AND I do
> it in the morning always)

Comment: The question about "their" could be asked separately, but it's already been discussed multiple times.  https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=singular+they  The summary is something like: *they* has been used as a gender neutral singular pronoun since sometime in the 1300s, so you should go ahead and use it without fear and it's probably not right to call it "trendy" ("trendy" trends usually last quite a bit less than 700 years).

Comment: @Juhasz - Mariya is quite correct in implying that there is a trend towards avoiding gender-marked pronouns when referring to people in general.

Answer (score 2):

The source you've quoted aptly describes common usage of adverbs like *often*, which are sometimes called *adverbs of frequency*.

Here's another source, the *Cambridge Dictionary*, saying basically the same thing, but with a little more detail:

> frequency | They usually go in mid position. They sometimes go in front position. They can also go in end position. *Always*, *ever* and *never* do not usually go in front position.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position

They give these two examples with *often*, one using it in the "mid position" (between the subject and the main verb) and one using it in the "end position" (the last item in the clause):

> *We **often** have friends to stay.*
>
> *We don’t see them **very often**.*

According to this [Google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=often+we+go%2C+we+often+go%2C+we+go+often&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coften%20we%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwe%20often%20go%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwe%20go%20often%3B%2Cc0#), "We often go" is much more common than "often we go," which is more common than "we go often."

But don't take the relative infrequency of "we go often" to mean that it sounds strange. It's fairly normal.

Comment: There is no **proper** word order in the example you quote: **Does she often dance?** is just as correct as **Does she dance often?**, although one construction may be more popular than the other. The author of the exercise was mistaken (which is not unusual).